# Cannot fetch image as binary

Tags: javascript, image, fetch-api, binary-data

I am confused by strange behavior of `fetch` on mobile devices, ios or android - doesn't matter. My goal is to load an image by its url via `fetch` and then represent the loaded data (a jpeg image, for example) as binary data (`Blob`). The image does really exist, I can open the url, no problem here. My code just repeats examples from well-known tutorials:

```
const response = await fetch('https://image-url');
const blob = await response.blob(); // here appears the problem apparently
new File([blob], 'image name', { type: blob.type });
```

But what happens is that this code throws an error on mobile devices (only there, desktop browsers are fine) like `TypeError: failed to fetch` at the moment when I try to treat loaded image as binary data - `await response.blob()`. Request's `Accept` header is `*/*`. The response comes back as `image/jpeg`. No CORS issues, the image's server has set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: @OliverNybo unfortunately, I didn't. Seems to be mob browsers' design choice.